# Enable hardware virtualization on Dell Studio 1555 laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, virtualization, bios, dell-studio

I am trying to enable hardware virtualization on my laptop but I can't find anything in the BIOS. How can I enable hardware virtualization - or does my system not support hardware virtualization?

Answer (score 1):

First of all your CPU has to support hardware virtualization (VT-X). The default CPU of a Dell Studio 1555 is AFAIK a T4200 which ha no VT-X suport.

If you have a different CPU check the complete list at Intel: [Intel® Virtualization Technology List](http://ark.intel.com/VTList.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the BIOS does not support it, you cannot, nothing you can do.

This tool can tell you if it is capable of virtualization or not:

http://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: This processor's advanced hardware support for virtualization has been disabled and "locked off" by some external influence - most likely by this system's BIOS as the system was booting. Since enabling hardware virtualization will allow faster and more secure virtual machines and their hosting operating systems to run at 100% full speed, you may wish to poke around in your system's BIOS to see whether you're able to find any references to "hardware virtualization" or "VMX", etc.

Comment: i got this Message from that software its i have but is disable?

Comment: It said YES?...If it is not in the bios, then is is disabled (crippled) by Dell for some reason, did you check all the places in the bios, some are buried at lower levels, double check.

Comment: @livetolearn If the processor supports it and the BIOS doesn't it may be possible to used hacked BIOS which will support virtualizaion. I can't provide any links for Dell, but searching could help. I managed to enable virtualization on my Acer Aspire 7720g this way.